# IOTA Documentation: which one is the official one?

Tags: documentation, java

**IOTA Docs**

I'm trying to learn all about the technical aspects of IOTA but I often find infos saying opposite things.
As an example the "Anatomy of a transaction" pages of the following sites:

- [iota.readme](https://iota.readme.io/v1.2.0/docs/the-anatomy-of-a-transaction)
- [domschiener.gitbooks](https://domschiener.gitbooks.io/iota-guide/content/chapter1/transactions-and-bundles.html)
- [docs.iota](https://docs.iota.org/introduction/iota-token/anatomy-of-a-transaction)

In particular the last is the one linked in the official IOTA website but I think an address is 81 trytes long; instead this documentation says that the address is a 27 trytes long String.

**IRI Documentation**

I'm also starting to read the Java source code of the IRI (IOTA Reference Implementation) but I can't find any documentation and/or comments to the code.
I'm reading and writing a recap of all the Java classes (otherwise I'll have to read it all over again) but I'd rather avoid doing something already done by others.

Is there an official documentation? Anything official at all?

Answer (score 2):

The IOTA Foundation is working hard in documenting all the aspects of IOTA by this days. You might want to wait a bit: new website coming soon and maybe the way documentation is handled will change. As of today I would say that the official doc is https://iota.readme.io/

Comment: I understand they're working hard but I think that for an "open source" project like IOTA documentation should be the first thing to make. Without a complete and up to date documentation it's hard for anyone to hop on the train of development.
I hope that with the Ecosystem we'll get what we need

Comment: I ttly understand what you mean. I am also struggling with some dev aspects (MAM, for instance). But, as we speak the IF is working to solve this lack of doc. I guess this is part of the "not production ready" state. But Doc is coming soon.

Comment: I'm sure about it, they're working hard. I simply think that anyone creating something this big should have written everything at least two years ago.
But now we only have to wait (hopefully not too long)
Thanks again Carpincho!